# c++ how to run an .exe file whose contents are stored in a char array?

Tags: c++, char, exe, execute

I'm making a specific program and i just wondered if I could do this:
 run a file whose contents are stored in a char array  ON WINDOWS.

this is the code that reads the executable and stores it in a char array:

```
filetoopen.open (C:\blahlbah.exe, ios::binary);
filetoopen.seekg (0, ios::end);
length = filetoopen.tellg();
filetoopen.seekg (0, ios::beg);
buffer = new char [length];
filetoopen.read (buffer, length);
filetoopen.close();
```

I heard something about RunPE and  I did some searching, I haven't succeeded in finding any piece of C++ code to use.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236460/c-using-windows-named-pipes

Comment: On which operating system? If it is Windows only (as I guess), please tag the question as such. And why do you want to do that? Why can't you write your executable into a temporary executable file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows how to Load an EXE File and Run It from Memory : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LoadExeIntoAssembly.aspx

Additional readings here :  [CreateProcess from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305203/createprocess-from-memory-buffer)  and here  :  [How to run unmanaged executable from memory rather than disc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224149/how-to-run-unmanaged-executable-from-memory-rather-than-disc)

Comment: This Is A C# example, not C++. Any C++ examples?